# What is the name of this creature in "Godzilla: King of the Monsters"?

Tags: character, monsterverse, godzilla-king-of-monsters

In ***Godzilla: King of the Monsters*** (2019), what is the name of the woolly mammoth titan? I found [this](https://www.godzilla-movies.com/topic/48836) post that refers to him as Behemoth but would prefer a more official source.

The creature was one of the new ones created for this series, not from Toho.

Comment: possibly related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101307/what-are-the-names-of-the-17-titans

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Mike Dougherty, it's **Behemoth**.

From an [interview](https://bloody-disgusting.com/interviews/3564330/spoilers-michael-dougherty-explains-monsters-godzilla-king-monsters-spoilers/) with William Bibbiani for Bloody-Disgusting from 2019.06.01:

> For example, one of the titans in King of the Monsters is a gigantic mastodon with human-like arms. [...] “That one is named Behemoth, so that’s a biblical reference, and he’s one of the few male creatures,” Michael Dougherty explained to ***Bloody-Disgusting***. “Because they always tend to be insectoid or reptilian or some combination of the two, and I really wanted another big, furry creature that looked like it could have survived during the Ice Age.”

In an [interview](https://www.slashfilm.com/michael-dougherty-interview-godzilla/) with slashfilm:

> **Q:** Rather than make you go through all 13 names, is there a place fans can look them up?
>
> **Dougherty:** Yeah, there’s a website, MonarchSciences.com. They’re working on it and obviously revealing it in layers to keep people intrigued.

Here's a [link](https://www.monarchsciences.com/) to that site, but as of yet, Behemoth isn't featured yet.